# Is there really a way to make carouselview to loop in a cycle with the list of elements provided in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

**I am using CarouselView.FormsPlugin of V5.2.0**
**Also attached my xaml carouselview code below:**

```
<cv:CarouselViewControl x:Name="cv"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}"
    ShowArrows="true"
    ShowIndicators="true"
                        IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                        CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="CornflowerBlue"
                        PositionSelectedCommand="{Binding MyCommand}"
    PositionSelected="Handle_PositionSelected"
    Scrolled="Handle_Scrolled"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
                        AnimateTransition="True"
                        ArrowsBackgroundColor="LightGray"
                        IsSwipeEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0">
</cv:CarouselViewControl>
```

**Binding MainViewModel in xaml.cs file as below: Inside the MainViewModel class only I have written the itemssource list 'MyItemsSource' list.**

```
BindingContext = _vm = new MainViewModel();
```

**MainViewModel class is below:**

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyItemsSource = new View[]
        {
            new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MobileShop.DashboardImages.Dimage1.jpg"), Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit },
            new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MobileShop.DashboardImages.Dimage2.jpg"), Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit },
            new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MobileShop.DashboardImages.Dimage3.jpg"), Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit },
            new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MobileShop.DashboardImages.Dimage4.jpg"), Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit },
            new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MobileShop.DashboardImages.Dimage5.jpg"),  Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit }
        };

        MyCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Position selected.");
        });
    }

    IEnumerable<View> _myItemsSource;
    public IEnumerable<View> MyItemsSource
    {
        set
        {
            _myItemsSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyItemsSource");
        }
        get
        {
            return _myItemsSource;
        }
    }

    public Command MyCommand { protected set; get; }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Now everything is working fine in carousel view. But when I try to swipe either right or left after reaching the end of items, its not swiping. That is, I am having five items and i can swipe left to go to fifth item, and vice versa. But after reaching fifth item, I cannot swipe left and cannot swipe right in first item. Thanks in advance for any help!!**

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/9453

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has not been implemented yet.

When I test in the Xamarin.forms `5.0.0.1487-pre1`. There is a new `loop` property added to `CarouselView`.

So I believe this feature will probably be released with in next version of 5.0.

You can also find some information through the relevant issues in Github.

[CarouselView doesn't loop](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8641)

[[Spec] CarouselView](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4996)

Comment: Hi @jack-hua-msft, In this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90387/how-to-do-a-carousel-page-with-a-complete-cycle-in-xamarin-forms), it is said that, if we use IEnumerable as type for the source list of carousel view, we can achieve loop cycle. Any idea?

Comment: No, I don't understand the solution.

Comment: Using 5.0.0.1558-pre3.  The Loop property is True as default.  Performs well on Android and completely freezes on iOS, at least v14. Setting Loop to False prevents the freezing obviously.